# Python - Dataframe group by time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a Dataframe with this SAMPLE (not original data) of records:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dikt, columns=['id', 'price', 'day'])

df:
    +-------+-----+-------+-----+
    | index | id  | price | day |
    +-------+-----+-------+-----+
    | 0     | 34  | 12    | 3   |
    +-------+-----+-------+-----+
    | 1     | 34  | 6     | 5   |
    +-------+-----+-------+-----+
    | 2     | 56  | 23    | 8   |
    +-------+-----+-------+-----+
    | 3     | 56  | 21    | 9   |
    +-------+-----+-------+-----+
    | 4     | 56  | 67    | 22  |
    +-------+-----+-------+-----+
    | ...   | ... | ...   |     |
    +-------+-----+-------+-----+
```

I want to group the price in a week like this:

```
+-------+-----+---------------------+
| index | id  | price               |
+-------+-----+---------------------+
| 0     | 34  | [12, 6]             |
+-------+-----+---------------------+
| 1     | 56  | [23, 21], [67]      |
+-------+-----+---------------------+
| ...   | ... | ...                 |
+-------+-----+---------------------+
```

In the above table, the prices were grouped by their day. For example 12 and 6 are in 3 and 5 day that can be in the first week. So they are together, and so on.

Comment: `'day'`: relative to what? The 3rd day of January 2020 was a Sunday, but the 3rd dat of February 2020 was a Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the day by 7 and add a column for the week number and group it into that unit. Which grouped data frames will be combined in a grouping without the week number.

```
df['weeknum'] = df['day'] // 7
df2 = df.groupby(['id','weeknum'])['price'].agg(list).to_frame()
df2['price'] = df2['price'].astype(str)
df2.groupby('id')['price'].agg(','.join).to_frame()
    price
id  
34  [12, 6]
56  [23, 21],[67]
```